# Expand appearance and outline stroke adds extra shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created a brush and used the brush tool to create an image made from strokes. When I go to expand appearance, it adds bits to the edges. This isn't happening when I use a regular straight stroke brush. 
Same thing happens when I do outline stroke.
[image: Line as a stroke]

[image: Line expanded]

[image: Art brush options]
[image: Appearance Panel]

Comment: Is there some other stroke applied? I've honestly never seen this happen unless there's *also* an additional stroke applied in the Appearance Panel stack.

Comment: Did you have a fill applied?  If so, try removing the fill first, before expanding.

Comment: I've checked the appearance panel and there is no additional stroke applied that I can see, also, there is no fill. 
This isn't happening with a basic default stroke, only the custom brushes I have added, I have added a photo of the art brush options above. 

I'm wondering if it is because it is not a closed path, and when it is being converted into an outline it is adding a fill in the process kinda thing (if that makes sense lol)

Comment: I think I figured it out, when I made the art brush it was a solid shape with fill and no stroke. I tried to make another brush but this time with just a stroke and no fill, the issue I was having didn't happen when I expanded the appearance of strokes with this new art brush.